# Codeigniter: Add a class to link if current_url() == href

Tags: codeigniter

Do you know of a way how to check if `current_url()` is equivalent to a link's href *without* using javascript? In doing so, if the href is the same then add `class="active"` to the link.

**Edit:** The first thing which comes to mind is making an array of all href values then using `foreach` to compare each one but maybe you have a better way than this?

Comment: what do you use to generate your links? views? template?

Comment: (I've moved the valuable answer from this question to the answer space - if you would like to post it as an answer yourself, then let me know and I will delete my copy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the anchor function in the URL helper like this.

```
if ( ! function_exists('anchor'))
{
    function anchor($uri = '', $title = '', $attributes = '', $apply_active = FALSE)
    {
        $title = (string) $title;

        if ( ! is_array($uri))
        {
            $site_url = ( ! preg_match('!^\w+://! i', $uri)) ? site_url($uri) : $uri;
        }
        else
        {
            $site_url = site_url($uri);
        }

        if ($title == '')
        {
            $title = $site_url;
        }

        if ($attributes != '')
        {
            $attributes = _parse_attributes($attributes);
        }

        if ( $uri == uri_string() AND $apply_active )
        {
            $active = ' class="'.$apply_active.'"';
        }
        else $active = NULL;

        return '<a href="'.$site_url.'"'.$attributes.$active.'>'.$title.'</a>';
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this so check a look for bugs. Call the anchor function like this:

```
anchor('my_page', 'My Page', '', 'active');
```

See the docs for how to extend helpers: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/helpers.html

**Edit:** OK I've tested it and updated my answer so it should work well now.

Comment: This works perfectly. While on the way home I was already thinking of extending the anchor() myself but looks like you beat me to it. What I did was shorten your code using ternary operators to save space. I'll post your code above so everyone can easily see it.

Answer (score -1):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question to the answer space)*.

Answer thanks to **Nick Pyett**:

```
if(!function_exists('anchor')){
    function anchor($uri = '', $title = '', $attributes = '', $apply_active = FALSE){       
        if(!is_array($uri)){
            $site_url = (!preg_match('!^\w+://! i', $uri)) ? site_url($uri) : $uri;
        }
        else {
            $site_url = site_url($uri);
        }
        
        $title = (bool)$title ? $title : $site_url;
        if($attributes != '') $attributes = _parse_attributes($attributes);
        $active = $uri == uri_string() && $apply_active ? ' class="'.$apply_active.'"' : NULL;
        
        return '<a href="'.$site_url.'"'.$attributes.$active.'>'.$title.'</a>';
    }
}
```